# how do I specify my user name in network to connect to an oracle data base

Tags: java, oracle, connection

I installed **Oracle** on **computer1** and I create a data base named **DataBase1** and a user named U**ser1** identified by **password1**, the ip adress of that computer is **1.1.1.1**

I connected that computer to a second one (**computer2**) that the ip address is **1.1.1.2**.

I created a **java program** who can connect to the data base by specifying **User1** and **password1** and there is not a problem when I run it in **computer1**

how can I specify the **user name** from **computer2** to connect to the same data base?

I tried some thing like "**1.1.1.1/user1**" , "**http://1.1.1.1:8888/user1**" but I can not connect...

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect to Oracle database in network using below command; provided sqlplus is included in path:

```
sqlplus User1/password1@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=1.1.1.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DataBase1)))
```

PFB java program to connect Oracle database in your network:

```
import java.sql.*;  
class OracleConnect{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
try{  
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.1.1.1:1521:DataBase1","User1","password1");  
Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select 1 from dual");  
.
.
conn.close();  
}catch(Exception ex){ System.out.println(ex);}  
}
}
```

Try both options from computer2 and share error if any.